# Why my cql query with double quotes doesn't work but with single quotes works?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-driver

Are double quotes not allowed in `cql`?

running this query works

```
val statement4 =
        s"""
           | INSERT INTO users (bucket,email,firstname,lastname,authprovider,password,confirmed,id,hasher,salt) VALUES
           | (1,'${testEnv.email}','fn','ln','${testEnv.loginInfo.providerID}','somePassword',false,${testEnv.mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID()},'someHasher','someSalt')
        """.stripMargin
```

but this doesn't (because I am using double quotes)

```
val statement4 =
        s"""
           | INSERT INTO users (bucket,email,firstname,lastname,authprovider,password,confirmed,id,hasher,salt) VALUES
           | (1,"${testEnv.email}","fn","ln","${testEnv.loginInfo.providerID}","somePassword",false,${testEnv.mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID()},"someHasher","someSalt")
        """.stripMargin
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour may come from cql, where double quotes are used to ensure that the case of the names of objects (like keyspaces, tables or [user-defined functions](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.0/cql/cql/cql_reference/cql_commands/cqlCreateFunction.html)), while single quotes are usually use to delimit values.

Note that if single quotes are not an option, you can use a [double-dollar sign](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/escape_char_r.html) to delimit those values.